# I am not able to split sentence Correctly using regex in JS the dot in between the sentences must not replace original sentence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

This the sentence i am using to separate splitting it by a dot

```
transcript = {'The latest survey of U.S. consumers from 451 Research indicates iPhone customer satisfaction of 98% for iPhone, and our active installed base of iPhones reached a new all-time high'}    


const substrings = transcript.split(/[.!]+(?!\d)\s*|\n+\s*/);
```

The output I am getting

```
substring = {'The latest survey of U.S','consumers from 451 Research indicates iPhone customer satisfaction of 98% for iPhone, and our active installed base of iPhones reached a new all-time high.'}
```

The ouput is wrong the sentence should not be separated according to the regex but because of "U.S."

Comment: See the linked solution, you can extend it by adding more specific exceptions (abbreviations) into Group 1 pattern if needed.

Comment: Also, the output you describe seems false, substrings might rather have three items : 'The latest survey of U', 'S' and the rest of the sentence

Comment: This is false you mentioned a link with a  false answer "xyz... cool." must be "xyz...cool" not ["xyz...","cool"]. My point is it must not separate the sentences with dots in between the sentences.